# How to uninstall oracle 10g on ubuntu 22.04g?

Tags: uninstall, oracle

I am trying to uninstall the oracle database xe 10g from ubuntu but I am unable. Please guide me.

Comment: How did you install it? What have you tried so far, exactly? What were the results? Edit your question with context and details. Help us help you.

Comment: Thank you for consideration to my question. I uninstall it successfully by using **dpkg**. Use the following commands `dpkg --list     (use this to get proper name of package)

then use

sudo apt-get --purge remove packageName `

Comment: If you have a solution, post the details of the solution as an answer.  Please don't post answers in comments!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I uninstall it successfully by using dpkg. Use the following commands
`dpkg --list`
(use this command you will get a list of packages install on your system. Find the package you want to delete from list.)  then use
`sudo apt-get --purge remove packageName`
(Package name should same as in the list)

In this way you can uninstall any package.

Comment: The package name is `virtualbox`, not oracle. `sudo apt purge virtualbox*` will remove all oracle vmware for any version. Can follow with `sudo apt autoremove` to remove the libraries/dependencies.